# Route to multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a webapi solution consisting of the main project with other projects as additional endpoints. If the additional projects could not be dependency of the main, that would be great too.

Structure would be something like:

```
MainWebApiProject   accessed as example.com/api/Values 
   SubProject1  accessed as example.com/sub1/Values
   SubProject2  accessed as example.com/sub2/Values
```

I've created a solution with the 3 projects. I tried setting up the routing in the startup.cs of the MainWebApiProject using Areas and without.

example with the Areas

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapAreaRoute("subProject1_route", "subProject1", "sub1/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    routes.MapAreaRoute("subProject2_route", "subProject2", "sub2/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute("default_route", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

then the controller inside SubProject1

```
[Area("subProject1")]
[Route("sub1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "sub 1 value1", "sub 1 value2" };
    }
}
```

Just not quite sure what I'm missing or doing wrong, or if this can really be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it is possible if the sub-projects aren't configured as dependency for the main project.

[Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in the new ASP.NET Core, is a feature to logically separate your namespace and views (where views are defined in the area). You would still need to have controllers in the main project to listen for that route.

I wonder, how do you run the sub projects? separately and totally independent of the main one? In that case you will definitely need a different protocol/port for them to be executed and routes will simply not work for them (within the main project).

Comment: If it needs to be a dependency, then ok, would just prefer if it didn't have to be. Ie. a different project I work on, there are projects that we can compile and just deploy the dll for one project instead of publishing the entire solution.  That does happen to be an old  .net 4.5 webforms solution, but was hoping I could do the same with asp.net core webapi.

Comment: @davek In this case you would need to setup your main project to scan for assemblies with specific configuration and then add them dynamically. It is totally a different subject. Possibly in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: awesome, i'll check that out tonight. I may just end up going with using Areas anyways. I may be trying to make this more complex then it needs to be.